# Getting list of years between two years?

Tags: php, datetime

I have this method :

```
public function getYears($startYear = 1990, $endYear = date ('Y')){
    $years = [];
    $date = new \DateTime();

    $years[$date->format('Y')] = $date->format('Y'); 
    while ($endYear <= $startYear){
       $date->add(new \DateInterval('P1Y'));
       $years[$date->format('Y')] = $date->format('Y');
       $endYear++;
    }
   return $years;
}
```

This piece of code doens't work, but you get the idea what I want ? How can i make this work ? thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: @Fky The post that you suggested is using the `strtotime` method. I want to use the methods from `DateTime()` class . Thx

Comment: Why not just use PHP's [range](http://php.net/range) function?

Comment: @Chester ALWAYS read a little bit more than just the accepted answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, this is really easy:

```
$arYears = range(1990, date('Y'));
```

Comment: Thx a lot, I need coffee :P

Comment: and if you really want keys `$arYears = array_combine($arYears, $arYears);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with a loop, you can do it this way:

```
function getYears($startYear = 1990, $endYear = date ('Y')) {
  $years = [];
  for ($y = $startYear; $y < $endYear; $y++) {
    $years[] = $y;
  }
  return $years;
}
```